# SQLite-Database connected with my PHP-Script but the prepared statement won't give me the data needed

Tags: php, database, sqlite, prepared-statement

```
    $user = $_POST['usr'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];

    try {
        $conn = new PDO('sqlite:../database/gameUsers');
        $smt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=':name' AND password=':password'");
        $smt->bindValue(':name', $user);
        $smt->bindValue(':password', $password);
        $userCheck = $conn->query($smt);

        $feedback = $userCheck ? "OK" : "Keine Daten vorhanden";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $feedback = $e->getMessage();
    }
```

How what I wonder about is actually quite simple. First:
Why does this happen? [Picture to error](https://gyazo.com/03e0cf451ed2938a8b4a631efa3a5047) (See the bottom part of the code to see the things that are 'missing' according to the error) and second: Why the heck do I not get a return into that statement? Did I write it incorrectly (because there is data inside that database, I checked it with sqlite3 on my command prompt) or is it just not accepting it for some other reason? Thanks in advance.

```
<p>
    <form method="post" action="login.php">
        <br>Benutzername:
            <input name="usr" type="text" required>
        <br>Passwort:
            <input name="pwd" type="text" required>
        <br>Eingeloggt bleiben?:
            <input type="checkbox" name="stayLog" value="Ja"> Ja
        <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Einloggen!">
    </form>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$smt` is a PDO::Statement object. The `query` method takes a string as parameter. To execute the prepared statement, use PDOStatement [execute method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). To get results from the (executed) statement use one of the [fetch methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

You should not enclose named parameters (eg `:name`) in quotes.